# How to create JavaFX 3D scene but disable rendering?

Tags: cloud, javafx-3d

I have a use case for JavaFX 3D in which I would like to construct a 3D scene in a cloud application where graphic rendering may not be supported, and then export that scene to an FXML file so that it can be rendered later on a desktop or mobile device.  I have FXML export and import methods working.

The information I have found so far indicates that JavaFX will simply issue an error if the appropriate hardware for 3D rendering is not found. Does anyone know if there is a way configure the JavaFX 3D system so that a scene can be constructed in the usual way, and then exported without going through the rendering step?

Comment: Try it.  Create a node hierarchy with 3D elements.  Don't place the nodes into a scene. Don't use [3D transforms or a 3D camera](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/ConditionalFeature.html#SCENE3D).  Use your existing FXML export and import methods on the node hierarchy.  Deploy your application on a server which [does not support hardware rendering of 3D elements using JavaFX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html) (i.e. uses a software pipeline) and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have tested the export without the camera and scene objects.  I was able to export successfully.  I have not tried it on a compute server without graphics hardware but eventually I will.